Would such a reference request question be considered on-topic?
Recently, I'm interested in a certain mathematical problem which amounts to solving a certain family of PDE's in different kinds of domains. For most domains, no closed-form expressions are known and people have to resort to numerical methods in order to get a solution. I wanted to get an idea of what numerical methods were the most popular and successful to tackle this problem, but I struggle to find any reasonably recent papers which study the problem from a numerical perspective.
Therefore I want to ask here : would it be fine to ask on the main site for references/papers which study said problem from a numerical/application perspective or would it be considered off-topic ?
Edit : Just to clarify my concern, I am worried that since the references I am looking for would most likely not be mathematics papers per se, but rather engineering, physics or chemistry papers, the question may be seen as not fitting for the site. As far as I can tell looking through the questions tagged reference-request, the references asked by OP are always mathematical in nature.
Thanks for your time.

Why would you think such a [tag:reference-request] question would be off-topic?

@J.W.Tanner because the references I'm thinking are not about mathematics per se, but about numerical approaches to solve the problem in real-life applications (which to my understanding comes up a lot in fields like biochemistry, neuroscience, electrical engineering etc...). I will edit the question to make my concern clearer.

@pie It's a reference to the moderator strike which happened last year, I should change my username at this point but I'm lazy to do so and haven't been very active on the site anyway.

clickbait title much? Maybe tell what kind of a request rather than saying "such"?

Requests for references to applied mathematics literature are on-topic here.
That said, your interests may be so specialized that better chances of a well-crafted reply exist in another SE site.  I'm thinking in particular of Computational Science for PDE solving software and related domain modelling topics.
